# 500 Server Error - Laravel - Hosting

Tags: laravel

Hola chic@s espero esten bien, tengo un problema con un proyecto en Laravel, lo subi a un hosting con CPanel, configure todo y la pagina anda bien, cree la base de datos en el CPanel e importe la que había creado para el proyecto, configure el .env para que la reconozca y aparentemente lo hizo, por que puedo loguearme y acceder al listado de usuarios registrados, el problema esta al registrar, es allí donde me tira el error.

El registro lo hice usando el register de Laravel con el controlador RegisterController.

les dejo el código:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/registerReady';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
          'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
          'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
          'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
          'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
          'passwordConfirmation' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
          'direction' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
          'zone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
          'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
      $photoPath = $data['user_pic']->store('public/userPhotos');

       return User::create([
         'name' => $data['name'],
         'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
         'email' => $data['email'],
         'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
         'direction' => $data['direction'],
         'zone' => $data['zone'],
         'phone' => $data['phone'],
         'user_pic' => $photoPath,
       ]);
    }
    public function showRegistrationForm()
     {
       return view('register');
     }
}
```

```
          LOGS
        [2019-10-29 21:30:12] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = gianmachellaf@gmail.com limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = gianmachellaf@gmail.com limit 1) at /home/venexcar/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home/venexcar/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
```

[stacktrace]

Comment: actualiza tu pregunta con el log de errores de Laravel, que encuentras en `tu-proyecto\storage\logs`

Comment: Ahí indica un problema de acceso, seguro que en el .env colocaste las credenciales correctas?

Comment: Si lo que estoy viendo es que están los datos antiguos, en el .env están las nuevas, lo raro es que lee la base de datos pero no guarda datos

Comment: Como comente anteriormente, tuve que crear una base de datos con usuario y password y luego importar la que ya tenia. en el .env configure todo con los datos de la nueva base de datos